# What is similar option in ubuntu for remote desktop connection?

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop

Is there any alternatives available similar to **Remote desktop in windows** systems?

Comment: are you asking about sharing your current Ubuntu desktop or connecting to another OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Remmina regularly. I can add the RDP to a list, and click on the one I want to use.

They have a self-named website, installation was quite trivial. I believe this will do what you want.

Comment: Reminna is already included with every Ubuntu Desktop install.